# rspec puts output test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm having trouble understanding how to test for output with `puts`. I need to know what I need to do in my RSPEC file.

This is my RSPEC file:

```
require 'game_io'
require 'board'


describe GameIO do
  before(:each) do
    @gameio = GameIO.new
    @board  = Board.new
  end

  context 'welcome_message' do
    it 'should display a welcome message' do
      test_in   = StringIO.new("some test input\n")
      test_out  = StringIO.new
      test_io   = GameIO.new(test_in, test_out)

      test_io.welcome_message
      test_io.game_output.string.should == "Hey, welcome to my game. Get ready to be defeated"
    end
  end

end
```

This is the file it is testing against:

```
class GameIO
  attr_reader :game_input, :game_output
  def initialize(game_input = $stdin, game_output = $stdout)
    @stdin  = game_input
    @stdout = game_output
  end


  def welcome_message 
    output "Hey, welcome to my game. Get ready to be defeated" 
  end


  def output(msg)
    @stdout.puts msg
  end

  def input
    @stdin.gets
  end

end
```

NOTE: I updated my RSPEC code to reflect changes I made to my test file given suggestions found elsewhere. To resolve the poblem completly I used the changes suggested by Chris Heald in my main file. Thank you all and thank you Chris.

Comment: For future reference: Once you've solved the question, it's better to put the solution in an answer instead of editing your question. If someone comes back to this question, it's hard to see what the original question was. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initializer should be:

```
def initialize(game_input = $stdin, game_output = $stdout)
  @game_input  = game_input
  @game_output = game_output
end
```

The reason for this is that `attr_accessor` generates methods like this:

```
# attr_accessor :game_output
def game_output
  @game_output
end

def game_output=(output)
  @game_output = output
end
```

(attr_reader generates only the reader method)

Thus, since you never assign `@game_output`, your `game_output` method will always return nil.

Comment: This was THE most helpful hint.. I also had to modify my test as well...I'll try to update my code to reflect the changes

Answer (score 2):

Just check you are sending it the message:

```
@gameio.should_receive(:puts).with("Hey, welcome to my game. Get ready to be defeated")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stub puts and print.

Perhaps the most fundamental way is to temporarily reassign STDOUT to a variable, and confirm the variable matches what you expect for output.

And Minitest has `must_output` as an assertion/spec.

The code is thus:

```
 ##
 # Fails if stdout or stderr do not output the expected results.
 # Pass in nil if you don't care about that streams output. Pass in
 # "" if you require it to be silent. Pass in a regexp if you want
 # to pattern match.
 #
 # NOTE: this uses #capture_io, not #capture_subprocess_io.
 #
 # See also: #assert_silent

 def assert_output stdout = nil, stderr = nil
   out, err = capture_io do
     yield
   end

   err_msg = Regexp === stderr ? :assert_match : :assert_equal if stderr
   out_msg = Regexp === stdout ? :assert_match : :assert_equal if stdout

   y = send err_msg, stderr, err, "In stderr" if err_msg
   x = send out_msg, stdout, out, "In stdout" if out_msg

   (!stdout || x) && (!stderr || y)
 end
```

Comment: Well, yeah.  But there is absolutely no reason why you can't use the code above, it is just plain Ruby.  "def is our stub" right?  But the stub does come from RSpec library.  I just wanted to show how it could also be done with Plain Ruby, no framework.  Or even patching Rspec, after all it is just plain Ruby.  As you can see from the accepted answer... it is mostly identical, right?